# Back tic in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, couchbase, sql++

I am wondering if there is a way to use a back tic in vb.net ?
I am using N1QL to query a Couchbase db and i have a reserved keyword in my couchbase docs which is number. In N1QL you just enclose that word in back tic and that allows you to use reserved keywords.

```
Dim qRequest = New QueryRequest()
qRequest.Statement("select meta().id as DocId, _id,_type,`number`,cname_text,status,action from Vodex where _type ='cname'")
```

even so i dont get an error i dont get the desired response from my vb.code

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: *"i dont get the desired response"*. But you thought that failing to mention what the desired response or the actual response are is the best way to get help with this particular problem?  You need to provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: If statement sent as it is it should work. You can try in query work bench and see if that works. Alias the number and see if that helps.

Comment: What i mean with with not the desired response is that i get nothing back for the number field. I know my code works in general as a run a N1QL query to set phone_nbr value with the number value for each doc and if i know query phone_nbr i get the expected value

Answer (score 0):

I created a bucket called Vodex with a primary index and one document in it like this:

```
key: doc1
{
  "number": 1
}
```

I then wrote a small console app. It's been a while since I've written VB.NET, so forgive this clumsy example:

```
Imports Couchbase
Imports Couchbase.Configuration.Client
Imports Couchbase.N1QL

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim clientConfig = New ClientConfiguration()
        Dim uris = New List(Of Uri)
        uris.Add(New Uri("http://localhost:8091"))
        clientConfig.Servers = uris
        Dim cluster = New Cluster(clientConfig)
        cluster.Authenticate("Administrator", "password")

        Dim bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("Vodex")

        Dim qRequest = New QueryRequest()
        qRequest.Statement("select meta().id As DocId, `number` from Vodex")

        Dim results = bucket.Query(Of Foo)(qRequest)
        Dim rows = results.Rows

        For Each o As Foo In rows
            Console.WriteLine(o.DocId)
            Console.WriteLine(o.Number)
        Next

        cluster.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Module

Friend Class Foo
    Public Property DocId As String
    Public Property Number As Integer
End Class
```

After running that, "doc1" and "1" are printed to console. It seems to work okay, even with backticks. If you're experiencing another issue, it is probably not because of the backticks.